# Write query for couchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

How to write simple query in couchDB for documents of this type

`{
       _id: q12312312, 
       _rev: 1-f591846a021c02a6014702f35cc8627c,
       mid: e1e410788853b1cfd7820b9092004686,
       uid, e1e410788853b1cfd7820b9092000f60
}`

I want to get documents by "uid". In SQL that would be done with this command: 
SELECT * FROM users_music WHERE uid="1edsae23wsa"

I have a view in CouchDB

```
 `function(doc) 
{
     if(doc.uid && doc.mid)
     {
         emit(doc.uid, doc.mid);
     }
}`
```

When I try to access this view from this link `http://localhost:5984/user_music/_design/music/_view/musicview?key=e1e410788853b1cfd7820b9092000f60`

I get 
`{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}`

Comment: If the JSon is really formatted as you excerpt, your document is indeed invalid. You'll need to have it show  `"uid": "your id"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`http://localhost:5984/user_music/_design/music/_view/musicview?key="e1e410788853b1cfd7820b9092000f60"`

Notice the quotes around the key.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :)